# How to use placeholder feature in ng-sortable?

Tags: angularjs, ng-sortable

any example of how to use this feature ?

A customized placeholder can be provided by specifying the placeholder option provided to the as-sortable item. placeholder can be both a template string or a function returning a template string. [ng-sortable](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable) , I have tried to put a template but its not appearing on the placeholder, I want the place holder to be a copy of the dragged item with low opacity.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I used this configuration for the "as-sortable" property

`$scope.dragDropMetricsOpts = 
            {
                orderChanged: function( event ){},
                containment: "#board",
                clone: true,
                allowDuplicates: false,
                placeholder: function( event ){
                    return "<div style="background: red;"></div>";
                }
            };`

Comment: Hello; I have done what you have stated but its not working, nothing is shown in the placeholder, I have even tried to log the event in the placeholder function but it did not work.